# How to work with angular/elements in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular8

I'am trying to learn how to create webComponent using @angular/element in Angular. my folder structure be like.

```
    webApp
   --src
     --App
        --app.module.ts
        --app.service.ts

        --ParentComponet
            --parent.component.css
            --parent.component.ts
            --parent.component.html

        --ChildComponet
            --child.Component.css
            --child.component.ts
            --child.component.html
```

**parent.compnent.html**

In parent.compnent.html i have called Childcomponent as child and passing array of json as input to child component to form list by calling ApiService in Parent. and it also having output if i delete from list it will emit **ID** from child to parent to call the delete service and delete it from backend.

```
<p>Welcome to Parent-Component</p>
<app-child [input]="childInput" (delete)="deleteItems($event)"></app-child>
```

**parent.compnent.ts**

Here i called ApiService and in ngOninit i hit the getApi method from api.service to fetch data from background and i assign the response to the **childInput** variable.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../app.service.ts';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childInput: any = [];
  @Input('getData') getData= '';
  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private toast: ToastrService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializing()
  }

  initializing(){
    this.apiService.getApi(`${getData}/get`).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp['status']) {
        this.childInput = [...resp['response']];
      } else {
        this.toast.error(resp['message'])
      }
    })
  }

  deleteItems(id){
    this.apiService.deleteApi(`${getData}/delete`,{id:id}).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp['status']) {
        this.toast.success(resp['message']);
        this.initializing()
      } else {
        this.toast.error(resp['message'])
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**ApiService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  
  getApi(url){
    return this.http.get(url)
  }

  deleteApi(url,data){
    return this.http.delete(url,data)
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent**

Here iam getting data from parent to form table. i used **header** variable to form table header dynamically.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('input') input: any = [];
  @Output('delete') delete =new EventEmitter();
  tableData:any=[];
  header: any=[];
  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableData=this.input;
    this.header = Object.keys(this.input[0]);
  }

  deleteItems(id){
    this.delete.emit(id);
  }
}
```

**ChildComponentHTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let head of header">{{head | titleCase}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
            <td *ngFor="let head of header">{{item[head]}}</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-delete" (click)="deleteItems(item.id)"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**AppModule**

In AppModule i have used ngDoBootstrap to convert my parentComponent to web component but the thing is i have called ChildComponent as child for ParentComponent and injected apiService for fetching data from backend.
will it be used as calling as html tag at outer of Angular Application because i have not yet mentioned about ChildComponent as webcomponent and i do not know how api service will work.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';
import { ParentComponent } from '../Parent/parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from '../Parent/parent.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApiService} from './api.service.ts'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService],
  entryComponents:[ParentComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector){}
  ngDoBootstrap(){
    const yourElement = createCustomElement( ParentComponent, 
      { injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('ang-table', yourElement);
  }
}
```

if i called in normal html page as html tag in outer the angular project as

```
<ang-table getData="https://198.1.16.216:800/"></ang-table>
```

will it work.If i used simple html in ParentComponent it will work but i used child-component inside parent component and also used Apiservice or how can i tell the DOM that it uses ChildComponent and Apiservice.

Comment: Ajai your question still not clear to me. Can you update your question with a little more explanation?

Comment: please share  your code and make it. ore clear where you are facing problem

Comment: I have explained my doubt please kindly check and let me know.